# npx thirdweb@latest create --contract is giving error

Tags: npm, node-modules, npx, thirdweb

When I try to run the comand it gives me error

```
EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\fahim\AppData\Local\Temp\fahim\if-you-need-to-delete-this-open-an-issue-sync-disk-cache\thirdweb:cli'
details:
{
  errno: -4071,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EINVAL',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\fahim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\fahim\\if-you-need-to-delete-this-open-an-issue-sync-disk-cache\\thirdweb:cli'
}
```

I don't know what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like we have an issue with the latest version of the CLI.

Thanks for letting us know - we'll work on a fix!

In the meantime, the previous patch version should work:

`npx thirdweb@0.9.13`